# Custom function with additional argument using Struts 2 REST plugin

Tags: java, rest, url, struts2, struts2-rest-plugin

Is there anyway to have additional arguments in the URL of a Struts2 REST plugin controller?

For example, I have:

```java
public class PersonController() implements ModelDriven<Object> {

    private Integer id;
    ...

    public String comment() { ... };
    // Getter and Setter for id
}
```

which is successfully reached with

```
[domain]/person/{id}/comment
```

However, what I would like to be able to is have a URL like

```
[domain]/person/{id}/comment/{commentId}
```

Comment: In HATEOAS this would be more like `/person/:id/comments` to the the comment IDs, then the links to each comment would be by the comment id, e.g., `/comment/:id`. Rails routes like this and it's convenient (in a way), but not the only way to do things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be *not* REST style to have such URLs. Instead, you can use two URLs to access different resources.

```
 [domain]/person/{id}

 [domain]/comment/{commentId}
```

On the other hand if you mix convention and rest style mapping you can use `namedVariable` or `regex` pattern matcher to achieve what you would like to have.