# How can i use multiple parameters in restful struts?

Tags: struts2

i'm trying the struts restful plugin  .. but i didn't find any solution to pass more than one parameter to my controll class ..
I put the parameters into struts.xml and but every time i can't use more than one

```
<package name="rest" namespace="/rest" extends="rest-default">

<action name="doctor/*"  class="hospital.services.rest.DoctorController">
             <param name="id">{1}</param>
             <param name="name">{2}</param>                 
            </action>
 </package>
```

i can't rich the second parameter .. any suggestion?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; what do you think `{2}` would be in this case?

Comment: i need to pass two parameters to my class controller .. "namespace"/doctor/param1/param2 something like this.. please note that i'm using the rest plugin and i need more than one parameter in my  put or post methods

Comment: You didn't use a rest mapper in the configuration. Trivially regex patterns work with params ([sorry if I remember that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31709418/573032))